# iOS 14 App Library Categorization by developer name

Tags: ios14

I installed an app from the firebase app distribution and in the App Library on iOS 14 it was automatically categorized in the folder with developer name (attached a screenshot). Does anybody know how to change this behaviour ?
[image: App Library Categorization]

Comment: It’s not possible to change that

Comment: Dev/Adhoc is placed in the developer name section.
Installed from Appstore is placed in the ‘ETC’ section.
Does this affect LSApplicationCategoryType?
Do I have to set LSApplicationCategoryType value?

Answer (score 0):

In App Library, your app will be under the developer name when you run it from Xcode. If you download the same, published app from the App Store, it will be correctly under the category that you set in App Store Connect e.i social, utilities, etc. So you wouldn't have to worry about it.